# grails war to include all grails-app groovy sources

Tags: grails

I cloned [grails-petclinic](https://github.com/grails-samples/grails-petclinic) and run `grails war`.

The war file contained classes, jars and several .groovy / .gsp files such as:

`5161 Mon Mar 16 14:02:12 IST 2015 WEB-INF/templates/scaffolding/Spec.groovy
2374 Mon Mar 16 14:02:12 IST 2015 WEB-INF/templates/scaffolding/_form.gsp`

and

`1885 Sun Nov 23 21:04:40 IST 2014 WEB-INF/classes/org/grails/samples/ViewSourceFilters.groovy`

I wish to pack the rest of grails-app `.groovy` files as well (controllers, domain, services, etc..).

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to include these?

Comment: It's irrelevant.. but since you asked.. to enable easy debugging using a product I work for.

Comment: you could look into how plugins do it, since they roll out with the source.  or you could just hook into the events when packaging the var (see the `eventCreateWarStart` hook)